# Experiencing something odd when using THREE.Raycaster for collision detection (r68)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've been using the `THREE.Raycaster` successfully to test collisions for many things in my game engine so far, it's great and it works well.

However, recently I've run into something quite peculiar which I cannot seem to figure out. From my point of view, my logic and code are sound but the expected result is not correct.
Perhaps I'm just missing something obvious so I thought I'd ask for some help.

I am casting rays out from the center of the top of a group of meshes, one by one, in a circular arc. The meshes are all children of a parent `Object3D` and the goal is to test collisions between the origin mesh and other meshes which are also children of the parent. To test my rays, I am using the `THREE.ArrowHelper`.

Here's an image of the result of my code - https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjW0f.jpg

In this image, the `ArrowHelper` objects are positioned (origin:direction) exactly how I want them. But yeah, there's something wrong with this picture, the code that is produces this is:

```
var degree = Math.PI / 16,
    tiles = this.tilesContainer.children,
    tilesNum = tiles.length,
    raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(),
    rayDirections, rayDirectionsNum, rayOrigin, rayDirection, collisions,
    tile, i, j, k;

for (i = 0; i < tilesNum; i++) {
    tile = tiles[i];
    rayOrigin = new THREE.Vector3(
        tile.position.x,
        tile.geometry.boundingBox.max.y,
        tile.position.z
    );
    rayDirections = [];

    for (j = 0; j < Math.PI * 2; j += degree) {
        rayDirections.push(new THREE.Vector3(Math.sin(j), 0, Math.cos(j)).normalize());
    }

    rayDirectionsNum = rayDirections.length;

    for (k = 0; k < rayDirectionsNum; k++) {
        rayDirection = rayDirections[k];

        raycaster.set(rayOrigin, rayDirection);

        collisions = raycaster.intersectObjects(tiles);

        this.testRay(rayOrigin, rayDirection, collisions);
    }
}
```

The `testRay` method looks like this:

```
testRay: function (origin, direction, collisions) {
    var arrowHelper = new THREE.ArrowHelper(
        direction,
        origin,
        1,
        (collisions.length === 0) ? 0xFF0000 : 0x0000FF
    );

    this.scene.add(arrowHelper);
}
```

Now, obviously, something is off about this image. The rays that collide with other meshes should be blue, while those that do not collide should be red.
It's clear from this image that something is totally out of whack, and when I inspect the collisions, I get some really off results. For a lot of those rays which appear blue in the image, I'm getting a huge number of collisions, something like 30 collisions for a single ray sometimes, but nothing for the others even when they are right next to other tiles.

I just can't figure out what it might be. How can it be that so many rays that should be blue are red? And how can rays from tiles at the edge of the level have blue collisions to tiles that do not exist?

Really scratching my head (read: bashing my head repeatedly) over this one, any help would be super appreciated!

Comment: > collisions = raycaster.intersectObjects(baseTiles);  what are baseTiles? are they the same as "tiles".  Also tiles =this.tiles.children is a bit confusing you are using "tiles" to refer to two different thing.  Best if you could make a jsfiddle for this.

Comment: @steveOw hey thanks for the reply, this was actually a copy/paste fail as I changed some variable names from my my actual code for clarity. I've since corrected it in the example. Sadly the problem wasn't that simple!

Comment: @steveOw have updated and changed this.tiles to this.tilesContainer, hope it's less confusing now. I'll see if I can get a fiddle going, will take me some time though.

Comment: I personally don't like tiles=this.tiles.children but I'm not saying that is the problem.  Suggest you try a different name e.g. cTiles = this.tiles.children.  Also try setting the recursive flag to make raycaster.intersectsObjects(cTiles, recursive = true) check for children - see [raycaster documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Raycaster).

Comment: It's not the problem of course but you mentioned it was confusing so I changed it for extra clarity just in case others had the same issue. I don't think I need the recursive flag because these objects don't have children and even if they did I wouldn't want to test collisions with them. I only want to test collisions with the children of this.tilesContainer

Comment: Perhaps you could place a marker sphere at every intersection just to show where the intersections are in space?

Comment: @RohanDeshpande three.js r.68 is two years old. I suggest you update to the current version.

Comment: @WestLangley Hi West, of course I know it's old, right now updating is going to break a number of things in my engine and looking at the release notes I don't see anything in particular that would influence this situation that would have changed, do you know of any? I'm trying to take the ray of least collisions here ;)

Comment: @RohanDeshpande There has been two years of bug fixes and upgrades, plus there are few users here who know how the library worked 2 years ago.

Comment: Again, I'm aware of that. I'll be trying to update my engine as a separate process very soon, but for now, I am not convinced that updating will fix this particular issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was actually outside this code and not, at least I don't believe, related to the outdated `r68` build.

When making the tile meshes, I needed to set **three** properties on them

```
tileMesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
tileMesh.updateMatrix();
tileMesh.updateMatrixWorld(); // this is new
```

I was doing the first two, just not the last one. Why this is necessary, I do not know, it seems a little odd to me but this is what fixed my problem. I had an `AxisHelper` in the scene, if you look at the original image, you'll notice that all the `ArrowHelper` objects that are blue are actually pointing towards the `AxisHelper`. This is really weird because the `AxisHelper` was added to the scene, not to `tilesContainer`. Adding the `ArrowHelper` objects to `tilesContainer` did not help.

The process to render the scene had the raycaster code run before the `AxisHelper` was added to the scene and before the initial render happened. The problem was also fixed if I moved the raycaster code call after the `AxisHelper` was added, but this was a hacky solution.

So the true fix was to add `.updateMatrixWorld()` to the tiles. The result now looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HfA0.jpg, which is correct (the `ArrowHelper` objects have been shortened in length so they don't overlap).

Big thanks to [Manthrax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/882264/manthrax) for his help on this one.

Comment: Documentation [Object3D](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Object3D) briefly describes .updateMatrix() and .updateMatrixWorld().  I think the last one is needed because your tilemeshes are children and updateMatrix() only updates the "local" matrix i.e. coordinates relative to the parent.

Comment: Hmm possibly, it doesn't really explain this part though *The problem was also fixed if I moved the raycaster code call after the AxisHelper was added, but this was a hacky solution.*

Comment: Yup, that is strange!

Answer (score 0):

I think you make some local vs global space error. I don't see so fast where exactly you go wrong, but all your position and direction calculations seem to be in the local system of the `tilesContainer`. Are you consistent in your local vs global coordinate system handling?

For example you add your `arrowHelper` to the `scene` instead of to the `tilesContainer`. It could be that the `tilesContainer` has some `rotation` set and because of this the arrows are pointing in another direction then you expected.

What happens for example if you add the arrows to the `tilesContainer` instead?

Comment: I thought this as well, but even if this was the case, this doesn't explain why the collision objects themselves, the ones created as a result of the ray cast, are so off. The arrowHelpers are not wrong. If I inspect the collision objects they are very much in line with what the arrowHelpers are displaying. I'll update the question soon with an example of the collision data